# tmux new-window ignores -c flag

Tags: tmux

I want new-window to start in the current pane directory.
For that I've used:

```
bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

But new window had the CWD of the tmux process i.e. the directory where I've started the tmux process.

This behaviour is observed only for `bind` command. Because all this works correctly:

```
new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
or
bind c split-pane -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

For some reason only `bind new-window` had this weird behaviour.

iterm2 3.4.14 + zsh 5.8 + oh my zsh + tmux 3.2a

Would appreciate any hints what can be the root cause. Thanks!